# Access Control on Site Content

Tags: liferay, portlet

I have a site within liferay 6.1 called abc which has super user test. Under the portal I have created two organizations and assigned two different users to these organization user1 to org1 and user2 to org2. What I want to achieve is that the portlets or the components that are available to the default/super user should be able to restrict the access based on the organization. For e.g. if I have a poc-1 portlet on super user account I should be able to restrict the access or customization of it for say org2. Please respond.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to give permissions for a specific portlet, only to some users.

For this, you can simply set the permissions by using PermissionUtil classes present in liferay. You just need to send the role id's of the ones who can view the portlets.

[Example](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/11404408)